# I need to add a whole list of people to an Active Directory Group

Tags: powershell, encoding, syntax, active-directory

I know how to add a *single* member:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Adobe-Acrobat Standard DC" -Members Lgonzalez
```

I want to add *multiple* members in a single operation. I know how to do it by enumerating them *literally*:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Adobe-Acrobat Standard DC" -Members Lgonzalez, zgonzalez, mgonzalez
```

However, how can I do it with a list of users *from an external source*?

I have them in an Excel document from which I can paste members.
How do I add them to the command from an Excel file with the correct syntax?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've *interactively* selected the usernames of interest in your Excel workbook and *copied them to the clipboard*, use the [`Get-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard) cmdlet to retrieve them as an *array* of usernames you can pass directly to `Add-ADGroupMember`:

```bash
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Adobe-Acrobat Standard DC' -Members (Get-Clipboard)
```

---

For a *programmatic* solution that extracts the usernames of interest from an Excel workbook *file*:

- Preferably, use the third-party [`ImportExcel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel#readme) module.
- Alternatively - assuming that Microsoft Office is installed - use the `Excel.Automation` COM Automation server.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative will be to save your excel file as csv then import it with import-csv and build the member list for add-adgroupmember

```
$members = (Import-Csv -Path $csvPath).Members -join ', '

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Adobe-Acrobat" -Members $members
```